# Getting full file path in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, pathname

I have a series of full file name (Complete file path). Issue is that all character in file path are in lowercase. I need to transfer this list to Unix server where the path names are case sensitive. I need to get the case sensitive path name from windows. How can I get that?

Comment: <span class="revision-comment">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763117/how-can-i-obtain-the-case-sensitive-path-on-windows
</span>

thought this might help

Comment: This has been answered previously - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763117/how-can-i-obtain-the-case-sensitive-path-on-windows

Comment: Really "sᴍᴀʟʟ ᴄᴀᴘs", or actually just lowercase?