# C# read case sensitive files/paths in Windows

Tags: c#, io, filesystems

[visual example of files I'd want to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X952.png)

[example of a really un-elegant workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs8lI.png)

I have a working copy of a repository where some people haven't been careful.
This working copy sometimes contains directories or files that only differ in case.
Is there a way for me to for example read from File.txt and file.txt whose contents aren't the same?

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763117/how-can-i-obtain-the-case-sensitive-path-on-windows

Comment: So to be clear you want the list of files which have the same name but whose contents aren't same?

Comment: My goal is to be able to read the contents off all files. 'File.ReadLines(@"foo.txt");' and 'File.ReadLines(@"Foo.txt");' return the same although they are different files with different contents.